# Using Mongodb and Radzen in Blazor Server .Net7, how do you display data on a RadzenDataGrid from an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, blazor, radzen

When using any properties that are individual variables the Datagrid works perfectly fine. When trying to render from an array, at best I've managed to get it to display as System.String[]. How do you go inside the System.String[] object to get the values stored within?

I have tried replacing Property="MajorRequirements" with the following with no luck:

```
Property = "MajorRequirements[0]"
Property = "MajorRequirements.0"
Property = $"{MajorRequirements}[0]"
Property = $"{MajorRequirements}.0"
```

Majors (example document):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("639d413260af0c7b888c6fef"),
    "Major" : "Sociology",
    "MajorRequirements" : [
        "Introductory Sociology",
        "Sociology Of Caring",
        "Sociology Through The Arts",
        "Social Problems",
        "Research Methods",
        "Sociological Theory I",
        "Sociological Theory II",
        "Research Method II",
        "Sociology Of Music",
        "Senior Sociology Seminar"
    ]
}
```

page.razor

```
@page "/page"
<h3>template</h3>

<RadzenDataGrid AllowFiltering="true" AllowColumnResize="false" AllowAlternatingRows="true" FilterMode="FilterMode.Advanced" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="20" AllowPaging="true" PagerHorizontalAlign="HorizontalAlign.Left" ShowPagingSummary="true" Data="@queryMajor" TItem="Majors" ColumnWidth="300px" LogicalFilterOperator="LogicalFilterOperator.Or">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Majors" Property="Major" Title="Major" Frozen="true" Width="0px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Majors" Property="MajorRequirements" Title="Major Requirements" Frozen="true" Width="0px" />
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

@code
{
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("database");
    List<Majors> queryMajor;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        queryMajor = mongo.LoadRecord<Majors>("majors");
    }
}
```

Mongo.cs (function used in page.razor only)

```
    public List<T> LoadRecord<T>(string table)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);

        return collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
    }
```

Majors.cs

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace project
{
    public class Majors
    {
        [BsonId]
        public BsonObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Major")]
        public string Major { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("MajorRequirements")]
        public string[]? MajorRequirements { get; set; } = null;

    }
}
```

table displayed from page.razor:

[image: image of page.razor displaying the table]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a (custom) viewmodel, that has the property 'MajorRequirements'
as a string. OnInit you than catch your records, and convert them to the viewmodel.

Which means you can join the array of strings to a single string.
(Comma separated) Which is perfectly able to be presented in the grid.